# Is there a way to remove certain objects and its value from an array other than using array_splice?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to remove the values for "email" and "phone_number" from my array before i can submit it as in my mssql, I'm not storing these information there. However, as much as I've searched online, the only way i can see to do this is by using array_splice. Is there any other way to do it?

This would be my array :

```
array:10 [
  "full_name" => "Prawn life"
  "address_city_id" => "173"
  "address_province_id" => "21"
  "address_district_id" => "4"
  "address_details" => "blah blah"
  "address_line_2" => "line 2"
  "address_postcode" => "40100"
  "email" => "test@gmail.com"
  "phone_number" => "12412455"
  "updated_at" => Carbon @1555379266 {#366
    date: 2019-04-16 01:47:46.113906 UTC (+00:00)
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is your friend:

```php
unset($array['email'], $array['phone_number']);
```

Comment: hey Joseph, thanks for the fast response! And yeah, it works! I never knew unset exists :O. Thanks again!

Comment: @UdhayanNair note that you can actually unset multiple values with a single call to `unset`.

Comment: hey thanks mate. another question, not sure if its appropriate to ask here, but i'll try. so i have an array :
`array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "nz8LHJ5iXmizAKZdnzlPMyH8ou6MIxOOBEd3WkdL"
  "quiz_id" => "38"
  "question" => "Alternator #1"
  "question_native" => "Alternator #1"
  "quiz_content_83" => "yes"
  "radio-group8" => "radio-group8_83"
  "quiz_content_84" => "f22"
  "quiz_content_85" => "nooo222"
  "quiz_img_84" => UploadedFile {#403 ▶}
]`
is it possible to check if the obj "quiz_img_84" exists? like i need a cross check for "quiz_img_83" and "quiz_img_85" but they do not exist.

Comment: Separate questions should be asked as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

`unset` should be doing the job like

```
<?php
$arr = [
  "full_name" => "Prawn life",
  "address_city_id" => "173",
  "address_province_id" => "21",
  "address_district_id" => "4",
  "address_details" => "blah blah",
  "address_line_2" => "line 2",
  "address_postcode" => "40100",
  "email" => "test@gmail.com",
  "phone_number" => "12412455",
    ];
unset($arr['email']);
unset($arr['phone_number']);
var_dump($arr);

?>
```

**output**

```
array(8) { ["full_name"]=> string(10) "Prawn life" ["address_city_id"]=> string(3) "173" ["address_province_id"]=> string(2) "21" ["address_district_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["address_details"]=> string(9) "blah blah" ["address_line_2"]=> string(6) "line 2" ["address_postcode"]=> string(5) "40100"}
```

Comment: hey Prafulla! Thanks for the fast response! Yeap, unset works fine! Thanks again!

Comment: @UdhayanNair I am glad it helped you.